# Using loop counter to print out pattern using 2 variables

Tags: java, loops, counter

Basically I'm trying to make a program to accept an integer between 1 and 10 and also an alphabetic character. It then outputs an appropriate pattern based on this value as a maximum width

For example a user enters an integer of 5 and a letter X the program prints out:

x

xx

xxx

xxxx

xxxxx

I can't seem to get it to print out anything, below is what I've got so far.. any tips are extremely appreciated!

```
import java.util.*;

public class pattern {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int New1 = 1, Linecounter = 1;



        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Number = sc.nextInt();

        if (Number >= 1 &&  Number <= 10) {
            Number = New1;
        }
            else{
            System.out.println("Error: Enter a number between 1 and 10");
        }

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        char letter = keyboard.next().charAt(0);

        for (New1 = 1; New1 <= 10; New1++) {
            for (letter = (char) Linecounter; letter <= 10; letter++) {
                System.out.print("" +letter+ ""); 
            }
            System.out.println();

        }}}
```

Comment: Is that your homework? what you want to do is something like for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
 for (int j = 0; j < number; j++) {
  system.out.print(str + " ");
 }
 system.out.println();
}

Comment: Structure your program so that you have methods `int inputNumber()` and `void printXs(int how_many)`, and your life will suddenly become easier. Also, rename `New1` so that its meaning is crystal clear from its name; ditto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off:

```
if (Number >= 1 &&  Number <= 10) {
            Number = New1;
        }
```

Sets Number = 1.  After this code executes, both Number and New1 are equal to 1.  You want something where Number is set to the input.  Now the loops need work.   You should have something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Number; i++) { //1 through Number
   for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      System.out.print(letter); //Print letter i times
   }
   System.out.print("\n"); //New line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this, you're searching for?

```
int x = 5;
char letter = 'x';

for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(letter);
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

The above outputs

```
x
xx
xxx
xxxx
xxxxx
```

Comment: Yes it's similar to that but the user must be able to enter which integer they want (between 1 and 10) and which letter they'd like to use.

Comment: @JohnnyC do you really want a complete example? You can simply mix your original code with this and it will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like homework, so I'll just bring you pseudo code. The idea is to do something like this:

```
for i in 1..x do
    for j in 1..i do
        print ('*')
    end
    println (''
end
```

(in fact, if you change the `println` for `puts` this becomes a valid Ruby script).

Anyway, the key here is: you need as many asterisk as lines entered by the user. As long as you print an asterisk in the inner loop *without* printing a newline, and call `println` in your outer loop, you are ok to go.
It is also important that you iterate up to the wanted value in the outer loop, but *only* up to the `New1` variable in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Integer: ");
    int userInt = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Letter: ");
    String userLetter = scan.next();
    String letter = "";

    for (int i = 0; i <= userInt; i++) {
        System.out.println(letter);
        letter += userLetter;
    }
}
```

This doesn't limit the input to be between 1-10, you can add a little `if` statement for that.